# Given the x and y components of the velocity, how can the angle be computed?

Tags: math, vector, geometry, angle

For a particle moving about in a Cartesian coordinate system (neglecting the z-axis), how can the angle of travel be computed given the x and y components of the velocity?

Before anyone says this isn't programming related, I am programming this right now, however, I don't know vector math.

For example, suppose the x and y values of the velocity are respectively 5.0 and -1.5, how would I compute the angle?

Comment: **This is definitely on-topic.**  Just because you don't use vectors at your job doesn't mean basic vector-math isn't *highly* relevant to programming.  That being said, this question is a duplicate of [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428365) [others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276855).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Javascript, I'd use `Math.atan2(1.5, 5.0)`. To convert to degrees, use `Math.atan2(1.5, 5.0)/(Math.PI/180)`. On Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: I downvoted because you don't give any explanation of why `atan2` should be used to calculate the angle given the x and y components of the velocity. What's the relationship between `atan2` and the velocity? I will remove my downvote if you add these details to the answer. Moreover, the question does not mention Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You need [`atan2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2):

> For any real arguments `x` and `y` not both equal to zero, `atan2(y, x)` is the angle in radians between the positive x-axis of a plane and the point given by the coordinates `(x, y)` on it.

Answer (score 3):

The angle in radians from the x-axis is given by:

```
arctan(vy / vx);  // vx > 0
```

You also need to handle the case `vx < 0`.

If you want the bearing versus true north, then you might want:

```
double bearing = 90 - arctan(vy / vx) * 360 / 2 / M_PI;
```

Answer (score 1):

The arc-tangent of the slope will give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The angle is the arctangent of y / x. Many languages have a 4-quadrant arctangent function in the math library that takes x and y arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful about what the angles are between. Arctangent, `atan(y / x)`, will give you the angle relative to the positive x-axis, but make sure that's what you need.